# Control Firefox application from another c++ program using xpcom

Tags: c++, firefox, xpcom

So far, all `xpcom` examples I saw are Firefox addons. You write some C++ code, build, and register it. This resembles Microsoft COM `in-process server`, but instead of Windows registry the component information is stored in Firefox profile.

Does Firefox have out-of-the box ability to control it from another process using same API? Somthing like COM's `local server application`

When you start a second firefox instance, it communicates with the existing firefox process and tells it to open a new window, then dies. I suspect it uses some remote form of xpcom.